# Why is my simulated Poisson regression mean not equal to the variance?

Tags: r, simulation, poisson-regression

I simulated a simple poisson regression model as follows

$x \sim Normal(2, 1)$

$\mu = \exp(0.6 + 0.9 x)$

$y \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$

```
set.seed(123)
n = 1001
x = rnorm(n, 2)
mu = exp(0.6 + 0.9 * x)
sim <- rpois(n, lambda = mu)
```

However, the mean and variance are not equal

```
mean(sim)
# 16.68731
var(sim)
# 349.5331
```

but the mean is quite close to the standard deviation:

```
sd(sim)
# 18.69581
```

I expected the mean to equal the standard deviation. Why is that not occurring here? How can I fix it?

I eventually want to be able to simulate a Poisson regression with multiple continuous covariates and at least 2 categorical covariates, Possibly with hierarchical effects. So any code to extend to that case would be great as well.

Comment: This is confused on several levels. The main problem is already explained in the first answer. Here is one more: Even for an unconditional Poisson, the mean does not equal the SD unless exceptionally the SD and the variance coincide at 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your simulated data `sim` are not Poisson. That is, they are not *unconditionally* Poisson, but only *conditionally on the predictor*. Thus, equidispersion does not hold - or, more precisely, equidispersion will hold *conditionally on the predictor*: if you simulate many times for a *fixed* value of `x` (or equivalently, `mu`), the result will be equidispersed. But then, that will not come as a surprise.

What you have is a case of a compound distribution, specifically, a [Poisson-lognormal distribution](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=poisson-lognormal+distribution): the parameter to a Poisson distribution is itself lognormally distributed.

Comment: Great explanation to something I completely overlooked there. Makes total sense. Thanks!